# IE resend Request after timeout?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, timeout, request

My work environment is Internet Explorer 9, a ASP.NET website on a IIS6 server and WebAccelerator.
When a user click on a button, a big process is created on server side that take between 1 and 10 minutes. But a strange behavior appears when we check the DB and the log file, we can see the request has been executed 4 times instead of 1.
On the log file, we trace the beginning of a process 4 time with a gap between each of 4minutes.
Is it possible that a timeout appear on the webbrowser because it receive no response after 4 minutes and choose to resend the request? Is it a way to configure or disable that? Another explaination come to your mind?

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself. It came from the F5 WebAccelerator in the "Destination Hosts" menu, the only row specified a "R/W" value of 240sec and a "Retries" option to 2.
The server side work take more than 4 minutes so it considere the request as "failed" and resend it 2 times.

I hope it will be able to help someone else.